# jquery 2.2.4 of Azure DevOps 2019 Update 1.1 is vulnerable

Tags: jquery, security, azure-devops, infrastructure

We're running an Azure DevOps 2019 Update 1.1 on premises and we run a security compliance testing.
We found that the jquery inside Azure DevOps is obsolete and should be upgraded to the latest one. Meanwhile I check on my Azure DevOps 2020, the same version of jquery 2.2.4 is being used.

Could someone enlighten me how to justify if the jquery installed on Devops 2019 is not able to be upgrade? any KB articles from microsoft would be helpful for me.

Warm Regards

RK

Comment: Hi @RagaKuswardhono, have you tried directly upgrading and installing the latest jQuery version on the host machine of your TFS server? Is it helpful to you? You can have a try. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Please try directly upgrading and installing the latest jQuery version on the host machine of your TFS server. You can download and install the latest jQuery version from [here](https://jquery.com/download/).